# openssl x509 csr signing operation results in an empty .crt file using V3, did the syntax change?

Tags: openssl

We have this command:

`openssl x509 -req -in device-auth-key.csr -CA /some/ca.crt -CAkey /some/ca.key -extfile v3.ext -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -set_serial 01 -days 6000 -outform pem -out device-auth-key.crt`

When issued on openssl v1.x, we get a valid device-auth-key.crt.

When issued on openssl v3.x, we get an {empty} device-auth-key.crt.

Did the syntax change?

Addendum:  There is an openssl.conf that defined a PKCS11 engine, when we deleted that configuration, it suddenly started outputting valid .crt files.

Supplementary question #1:  Without -engine pkcs11 on the command line, why did the engine conf change the behavior?

Supplementary question #2:  How to get verbose output out of openssl v3.x? The help doesn't provide 'verbose' anywhere.

tyia